# What is the modern approach to configure multiple cache managers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching

Situation: my spring-boot project has two objects in which I need to cache data. The problem is that the settings for expire time must be different for the two objects.
I found a lot of information on the web about how i can set up a cache manager, but I did not understand which of these methods can be used in modern industrial code.
Please tell me how to configure settings for 2 different cache managers and if you need cache managers at all? My head is in a mess.

p.s. I don't want to use third-party dependencies like ehcache.

example:

```
public class Repository1(){
  @Cacheable("Repository1.findAllImportantThings")
  public Map<Long, String> findAllImportantThings() {...}
}

public class Repository2(){
  @Cacheable("Repository2.findOnlyOne")
  public Map<Long, String> findOnlyOne(String id) {...}
}
```

There can be more methods in a class. But the point is that I need to set different TTLs for these two classes

Comment: Please, provide some code to clarify your problem

Comment: @SemyonKirekov Added a little more description

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have different cache TTL then you need `cacheManager`, if in case all the caches have same TTL then it is not required.
You can do it this way :

```js
@Bean
fun cacheManager(connectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory): RedisCacheManager {

  val oneHourTTLCacheConfig = cacheConfigWithTTL(60) //TTL for cacheKey-1
  val fourHoursTTLCacheConfig = cacheConfigWithTTL(240) //TTL for cacheKey-2

  val cacheConfigurations = mapOf(
    "cacheKey-1"
    to oneHourTTLCacheConfig,
    "cacheKey-2"
    to fourHoursTTLCacheConfig
  )

  return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
    .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.THIRTY_MINUTES_DEFAULT_TTL))
    .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigurations)
    .build()
} // Sets default TTL to 30 minutes if the other cacheKeys don't require any different configuration

private fun cacheConfigWithTTL(ttlInMinutes: Long): RedisCacheConfiguration =
  RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
  .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(ttlInMinutes))
  .disableCachingNullValues()

private fun redisCacheConfiguration(duration: Duration): RedisCacheConfiguration =
  RedisCacheConfiguration
  .defaultCacheConfig()
  .entryTtl(duration)
```

You can add this to your cache configuration class. Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as far as I understand redis uses a lightweight database underneath.
Is there any native spring implementation? For example I read about ConcurrentMapCacheManager or maybe coffie(Although this, too, plugs in as a separate dependency.).  Or is it a legacy technology?  I apologize for my silly questions :)